# Spring Data mongodb: adding credentials for MongoDb access

Tags: xml, mongodb, credentials, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following working configurations in my Spring application:

```
<mongo:mongo id="myRs" replica-set="myhost:27017">

  <mongo:options max-wait-time="1500"
                   connect-timeout="30000" />
</mongo:mongo>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <property name="writeResultChecking" value="EXCEPTION"/>
    <property name="writeConcern" value="FSYNC_SAFE"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="myRs"/>
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="mydb"/>
</bean>
```

Now all I want to do is to set up username/password for accessing the mongo database without changing my code (i.e. only by updating the Spring app context xml file). Is that possible? If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass username password like this to MongoTemplate. Using **PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer** you can even read the username and password from a property file.

```
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <property name="writeResultChecking" value="EXCEPTION"/>
    <property name="writeConcern" value="FSYNC_SAFE"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="myRs"/>
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="mydb"/>
    <constructor-arg name="userCredentials" ref="userCredentials"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userCredentials" class="org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials">
    <constructor-arg name="username" value="username" />
    <constructor-arg name="password" value="password" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I have to set up the users on the DB side. I have replica sets for each environment. Do I need to manually add the credentials to each mongo master using mongo shell? Is there a better way?

Comment: Does the above UserCredentials bean work with replica sets? It seems there is no username/password choice for replica sets? (at least for MongoDb 2.2) http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/administration/replica-sets/#replica-set-security

Comment: I have not played with replica sets so not sure how that can be done.