# how to get error messages from mongoRepository.save()

Tags: spring-data, mongodb-java

I'm using mongoRepository.save() but cannot get error information for when duplicates prevent insertion.
As a test I'm inserting a duplicate username and mongo simply ignores it. but when username is unique it is inserted as expected.

See below for my service class:

```
package com.onlinedateshow.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.onlinedateshow.data.model.User;
import com.onlinedateshow.data.repo.user.UserRepository;
import com.onlinedateshow.model.ui.RegisterUI;
import com.onlinedateshow.model.util.RegisterMapper;

@Service
public class RegisterService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate template;

    public String addUser(RegisterUI registerData) {

        User newUser = RegisterMapper.toPersistenceBean(registerData);

        try{

            //does not return error, if duplicates are found, silently 
            //ignores the query
            User saveduser = userRepo.save(newUser);


            //below is what I want but don't know how to get it from a repository
            //String error = template.getDb().getLastError().getErrorMessage();
            //return error;
            return null;


        }catch(Exception e){
            return e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }
    }


}
```

and this is my UserRepository interface:

```
package com.onlinedateshow.data.repo.user;


import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;

import com.onlinedateshow.data.model.User;

public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String>,
PagingAndSortingRepository<User, String> {
    User findByEmail(String email);

    User findById(String id);

    User findByUserName(String userName);
}
```

And this is my XML file which sets up the MongoDbFactory:

```
<!-- Activate Spring Data MongoDB repository support -->
    <mongo:repositories base-package="com.mydata.repo.user" />

    <!-- MongoDB host -->
    <mongo:mongo host="${mongo.host.name}" port="${mongo.host.port}" />
    <mongo:db-factory dbname="${mongo.db.name}" />

    <!-- Template for performing MongoDB operations -->
    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate"
        c:mongo-ref="mongo" c:databaseName="${mongo.db.name}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you configure the appropriate `WriteConcern` on `MongoTemplate` or the `MongoDbFactory` implementation.

The JavaDoc for the relevant `MongoTemplate` method is [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#setWriteConcern%28com.mongodb.WriteConcern%29), the one for `SimpleMongoDbFactory` is [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/SimpleMongoDbFactory.html#setWriteConcern%28com.mongodb.WriteConcern%29).

Comment: Thank you Oliver, any idea how to configure MongoDbFactory with Spring? I can't find this anywhere. I'm updating my post with my XML config.

Comment: I've updated the post to contain links to the relevant parts in the JavaDoc.

Comment: Many Thanks Oliver! I kept looking and looking and finally found a way to add the concern into the XML, I needed  <property name="writeConcern" value="SAFE"/> in my Bean declaration. The following link also has a fuller example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16531663/spring-data-mongodb-adding-credentials-for-mongodb-access